# Importing an SVG file and restraining pan/zoom with D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm currenlty making a website with an SVG map of the world.
I'm trying to make it fullscreen, zoomable and pannable.
The problem now is that I can't restrain the panning to a certain box, since I don't seem to be understanding translateExtent properly.

My HTML (PHP) code looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="svgContainer">
    <?php
        $svgContent = file_get_contents('maps/BlankMap-World.svg');
        echo $svgContent;
    ?>
  </div>
  <script src="zoompan.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JavaScript code like this:

```js
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

var svg = d3.select("#allSvg") // The SVG file contains the ID
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
.on('zoom', function(event) {
    svg.selectAll('path')
    .attr('transform', event.transform);
});

svg.call(zoom);
```

If I add a translateExtent property like this:

```js
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]) // <-- Here
  .on('zoom', function(event) {
    svg.selectAll('path')
      .attr('transform', event.transform);
  });
```

It makes the panning and zooming stop working.
I looked for a solution to my problem and it seem to vary quite a lot depending on the source, maybe because of the different versions of D3.js?

I thought maybe D3.js isn't the proper library for this use since the world map has too many paths, but I'm not sure what else I could use.

I'd greatly appreciate your support on this, if something is not clear enough I'd love to give more details.